# Adding style files

Tags: texlive, dirtree

My question is related to [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) but the solutions don't work and the comments are very cluttered with not all comment information added to the answers (I did read the comments).

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and the most recent TeX Live.  My directory is located at `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex`.  I added a folder called `style` to place Jubob's Matlab style file he created.  On the linked thread, they say only older versions need to run `texhash`.  I can tell you not running and running texhash doesn't work.  When I didn't run texhash, TeX Live couldn't find the style file.  When I run `texhash`, it says

```
directory not writeable skipping... done.
```

I ran `sudo texhash` as well but the output is the same.

How can we add a style file and make it available on the whole system in LaTeX with the current version of TeX Live.

From @DavidCarisle's comment, I have

```
dustin@dustin:~$ kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'.:{/home/dustin/.texlive2013/texmf-config,
/home/dustin/.texlive2013/texmf-var,
/home/dustin/texmf,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,}//
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use the tree rooted in `/usr/share/texmf`; it should rather be the one rooted in `/usr/local/share/texmf` (creating the necessary directories, in not existent).

Comment: `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'` will show you the effective search path on your system. Directories prefixed with `!!` require texhash, directories followed by `//` subdirectories are searched recursively

Comment: @dustin I don't have a TeX Live/Debian at the moment, but the value shown should be `/home/<username>/texmf`.

Comment: @dustin Just create the `texmf` directory in your home and in it `tex/latex/matlab`, where you'll put the `.sty` file. No `texhash` will be needed.

Comment: so `/home/dustin/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage/mypackage.sty` should work and not need texhash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place for adding personal style files is in `TEXMFHOME` that, on GNU/Linux systems, should be found in

```
/home/<username>/texmf
```

The directory is not automatically created upon installation, because the installer never acts on users' space. So

```
mkdir -p ~/dustin/texmf/tex/latex/jubobsmatlab
cp jubobsmatlab.sty ~/dustin/texmf/tex/latex/jubobsmatlab
```

will suffice in order that the TeX system will be able to find the file. Change `jubobsmatlab` into the real name.