# How to use Iwona as sans serif font?

Tags: sans-serif

I feel stupid. The [Iwona package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/iwona/?lang=en) seems to load Iwona as `\rmfamily` font but I want to use it as sans serif font, after all it is a sans serif font... How do I get it as the `\sffamily` font?

---

Example for clarification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iwona}

\begin{document}
This should be Computer Modern but is Iwona

\sffamily
This should be Iwona but is Computer Modern Sans Serif
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I just made a very simple document with `Iwona` and it's sans serif

Comment: yes... But it doesn't load into the `\textsf{}` command but it goes as default font

Comment: Hm, I not sure I understand you correctly. Do you want to have the font sans serif for the whole document? Does `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}` help then?

Comment: Hm it's very much Friday afternoon and I am not making a good work at explaining I guess. I would need to do something like: (pseudocode)
`\temp = \rmdefault; \usepackage{iwona}; \sfdefault = \rmdefault; \rmdefault=\temp;`

Comment: @jonalv prefix assignments with `\let` as in  `\let\temp=\rmdefault` and that's exactly what you should do

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh that's so easy! It really is Friday... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepare a file `sansiwona.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{sansiwona}

\DeclareOption{regular}{\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}}
\DeclareOption{light}{\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwonal}}
\DeclareOption{condensed}{\edef\sfdefault{\sfdefault c}}
%\DeclareOption{mathnoalias}{\let\define@iwona@mathversions\relax}
\DeclareOption{math}{%
  \let\define@iwona@mathversions a%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{mathnoalias}{iwona}%
}

\ExecuteOptions{regular}
\ProcessOptions

\let\sansiwona@saved@rmdefault\rmdefault
\let\sansiwona@saved@bfdefault\bfdefault

\RequirePackage[mathnoalias]{iwona}

\let\rmdefault\sansiwona@saved@rmdefault
\let\bfdefault\sansiwona@saved@bfdefault
\mathversion{normal}

\endinput
```

Then the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{sansiwona}

\begin{document}

What font will this be?

{\sffamily And this? \bfseries And this?}

$a+b=\sum$

\mathversion{iwona}

$a+b=\sum$

\end{document}
```

will do the right thing, because the “wrong” settings made by `iwona.sty` are reverted.

Put `sansiwona.sty` where TeX will find it, see [Adding style files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175210/adding-style-files)

[image]

The `math` option is needed only if you need Iwona Math.

Comment: Aren’t the two occurrences of `mathnoalias` redundant?